# Getting Inflate exception inconsistently in Android

Tags: android, xml, layout-inflater, forceclose

I am getting the Inflate exception inconsistently on my emulator and device but sometimes it works fine

Its showing that in xml at line -16, i have the problem coz I am using two images one above the other

I have a bitmap image and undeneath I kept a .png image.

Is this becoz of the Images which I have in xml? nearlyI have 10 Images in my xml

I am running this application in an emulator with 800 cross 480 resolution

I dont know how to fix this, any help is always appreciated.

Logcat showing these messages

```
 10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.msat.carhome.clusters/co.msat.carhome.clusters.ClustersActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
 10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
 10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
   10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
   10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
   10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
   10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    at co.msat.carhome.clusters.ClustersActivity.onCreate(ClustersActivity.java:53)
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    ... 11 more
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    ... 22 more
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
  10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
    10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
    10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
     10-09 09:39:34.667: E/AndroidRuntime(339):     ... 25 more
     10-09 09:44:34.836: I/Process(339): Sending signal. PID: 339 SIG: 9
     10-09 09:54:16.536: D/AndroidRuntime(368): Shutting down VM
     10-09 09:54:16.536: W/dalvikvm(368): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.msat.carhome.clusters/co.msat.carhome.clusters.ClustersActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
    10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
    10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
      10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class <unknown>
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
     10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
    10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
   10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
   10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
   10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
   10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):   at co.msat.carhome.clusters.ClustersActivity.onCreate(ClustersActivity.java:53)
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    ... 11 more
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
 10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
 10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):     ... 22 more
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f070001}
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1681)
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
  10-09 09:54:16.667: E/AndroidRuntime(368):    ... 25 more
```

This my xml code

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/my_ph"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/meter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pointer1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
    android:background="@+id/meter"
    android:visibility="visible" /> 

<!--
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="170dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip"        
    android:src="@drawable/meat_speedometer_needle01"
-->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rpm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="290dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pointer2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="290dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
    android:background="@+id/rpm"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/leftarrow"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="170dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightindicator"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rightarrow"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text11"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:text="30&apos;C" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text12"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/battery"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="70%" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text13"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="105dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fuel"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="25L" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This is my java code

```
  public class ClustersActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
// ViewFlipper vf;
ImageView img, img1, rightindicator, pointer1, pointer2;
Bitmap bitmap;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
private IMyRemoteService remoteService;
private boolean started = false;
private RemoteServiceConnection conn = null;
private Handler serviceHandler;
private int enginRPM;
private int batteryLevel;
private int temperature;
private static int speed;
private Task myTask = new Task();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.cluster);
    getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    startService();
    bindService();
    System.gc();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.meat_speedometer_needle01);
    rightindicator = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rightindicator);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.meter);
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rpm);
    pointer1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pointer1);

    pointer1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    pointer1.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
    pointer1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    pointer2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pointer2);
    pointer2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    pointer2.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
    pointer2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final Animation fadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.fade_in);
    final Animation fadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.fade_out);
    // rightindicator.startAnimation(animationScale);
    rightindicator.startAnimation(fadein);
    rightindicator.startAnimation(fadeout);
    serviceHandler = new Handler();
    serviceHandler.postDelayed(myTask, 1000L);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your java class where you inflate this xml?

Comment: android:background="@+id/meter"
this line gives error

Comment: @Andro Selva , I posted the java code.

Comment: android:background="@+id/meter" this is your problem as it has been suggested already.

Comment: @V.J. You should have added it as the answer my friend. You were right.

Comment: @AndroSelva Thanks dear. i have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `android:background="@+id/meter"` is where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks,please see the comments below the samir's answer. I am getting this error inconsistently. earlier couple of weeks before it was working fine but not now

Comment: the background of "@+id/meter" is "@drawable/background"

So why you don't give the same background for the "@+id/pointer1"..??

Comment: If I do so I cant load a bit map to that Imageview dynamically, I am loading a bitmap to that imageview i.e to  @+id/pointer1

Comment: if you able to set the bitmap dynamically to meter then you also do the same for the pointer...

Comment: no i am not loading any bitmap to meter, its only background image

Answer (score 5):

Use `drawable` instead of `@+id`

```
   android:background="@drawable/meter"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont have any image named meter in my drawable folder, let me try.

Comment: @Raghav are you trying to set the src of first ImageView to the Second ImageView then?

Comment: @Andro Selva  no I have two imageviews one above the other the underneath image is a speedometer image and the upper one is an imageview(its for needle) to which i am setting a bitmap dynamically in code, so i kept the undeneath image as a background(android:background="@+id/meter")

Comment: Is it a wrong way? which i am doing.can u suggest what code should I replace there

Comment: @Andro Selva , I have that line in order to keep the needle at the center of the sppedometer image, If I remove that line it will be displaced some where instead of the center to speedometer

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error:

In Manifest:

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="true"
```

In .xml file, you must remove the below code:

```
android:src="@drawable..
android:background="@drawable...
```

Because the error is out of memory error. You should review code to handle memory